# BadAuth response when trying to create primary key with Tpm2Lib

Tags: c#, tpm

Following examples for the Microsoft TPM library ( https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/master/TSS.NET/Samples/Signing/Program.cs ). Trying to create a primary key that will be used to sign messages fails with `Error {BadAuth} was returned for command CreatePrimary`

I look up the value of OwnerAuthFull in the registry at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TPM\WMI\Admin` and let's say the value is "foo/bar=". This is also displayed when I run Get-Tpm on the command line.

```
Tpm2Device tpmDevice = new TbsDevice();
                tpmDevice.Connect();
                var tpm = new Tpm2( tpmDevice );
                var authValueRegistry = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( "foo/bar=" );
                var ownerAuth = new AuthValue( authValueRegistry );
                var keyTemplate = new TpmPublic( TpmAlgId.Sha1,                                  // Name algorithm
                                                ObjectAttr.UserWithAuth | ObjectAttr.Sign |     // Signing key
                                                ObjectAttr.FixedParent | ObjectAttr.FixedTPM | // Non-migratable 
                                                ObjectAttr.SensitiveDataOrigin,
                                                null,                                    // No policy
                                                new RsaParms( new SymDefObject(),
                                                             new SchemeRsassa( TpmAlgId.Sha1 ), 2048, 0 ),
                                                new Tpm2bPublicKeyRsa() );
                Console.WriteLine( "Made template" );

                var keyAuth = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
                TpmPublic keyPublic;
                CreationData creationData;
                TkCreation creationTicket;
                byte[] creationHash;
                Console.WriteLine( "try create key" );
                var keyHandle = tpm[ownerAuth].CreatePrimary(
                    TpmRh.Owner,                            // In the owner-hierarchy
                    new SensitiveCreate( keyAuth, null ),     // With this auth-value
                    keyTemplate,                            // Describes key
                    null,                                   // Extra data for creation ticket
                    new PcrSelection[ 0 ],                    // Non-PCR-bound
                    out keyPublic,                          // PubKey and attributes
                    out creationData, out creationHash, out creationTicket );    // Not used here
```

I expect to create a key and continue running however CreatePrimary() throws an exception with message `Error {BadAuth} was returned for command CreatePrimary`

Answer (score 1):

Forget `ownerAuth` and do this:

```
var keyHandle = tpm.CreatePrimary(
                    TpmRh.Owner,                            // In the owner-hierarchy
                    new SensitiveCreate( keyAuth, null ),     // With this auth-value
                    keyTemplate,                            // Describes key
                    null,                                   // Extra data for creation ticket
                    new PcrSelection[ 0 ],                    // Non-PCR-bound
                    out keyPublic,                          // PubKey and attributes
                    out creationData, out creationHash, out creationTicket );
```

Which you can infer from this github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/issues/43#event-2651641565